# How do I pass information from iOS to react native on startup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

**Edit**

To clarify, I am trying to open an attachment from an email in my app.  So the data needs to be passed into React on initialization of the app as well as while it's open.

**Original**

I’m very new to mobile app dev, but I’m trying to pass a filename through ios to react native.

The RN code for passing props when the app launches

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"driveby"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

However, this method only seems to execute when the app starts.  When we open the file, we need to use the `openFile` method.  The openURL method is correctly getting the URL of the file, but I can’t figure out how to pass it to the RCTRootView.

I would love if I could just edit the props in the rootViewController, but I couldn't find a way to do this by reading the RN source code (though I'm new to objective C and don't fully understand the code).  My hunch is that I have to rerender the view with new props.

I don't think it's the correct, but I attempted to create a new rootview and supply it to the rootViewController, but I got a “TypeError: expected dynamic type `not null/object/array’, but had type`null’.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  NSDictionary *urlDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"url", url, nil];

  NSLog(@"####################### Open URL");
  NSLog(@"Open URL:\t%@\n" "From source:\t%@\n" "With annotation:%@", url, sourceApplication, annotation);  //url is shown here!
  //NSString *filepath = [url path];
   //...

   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                       moduleName:@"driveby"
                                                initialProperties:urlDict
                                                    launchOptions:urlDict];
   rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

   self.window.rootViewController.view = rootView;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this. If you use Native Modules, you can call an ObjC function from your JS code. In that case you will not need to access RCTRootView or the AppDelegate and you can reduce the amount of ObjC code you need to write

Comment: @dentemm thanks for the response.  I've added a comment on the response below with a follow up question

Answer (score 0):

In React Native the mechanism by which you pass information between your JavaScript code and native code is via native modules.

You can create a bridge module and call that particular method from the JS side to supply your view with the URL you specify.

On the flipside, you can also use an event emitter to emit a URL to an event handler on the JS side, which can then open that file when it receives an event.

Take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html), this should help you out with what you need.

Comment: Ok, I've already set up native modules to work.  The confusion is that the file gets opened by the application and the only place I can find a reference to its location is is in the openUrl method in the AppDelegate.

Are you suggesting that I store the file URL somewhere on the application singleton and retrieve it via native modules?

Comment: How come only the AppDelegate has access to the file? Personally I wouldn't access it through the app singleton, but try to make it more reusable

Comment: @dentemm The file is opened from email attachment, or from a website.  The [ios documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1) says that it should be included in the launch options in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but it wasn't there.  The only place I've seen to get the URL is in the openUrl callback.

Comment: @dentemm specifically I've been working off these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285506/handling-files-opened-from-outside-sources-in-ios-swift

Comment: Okay, I have not yet done this, but you could probably create a native module from the AppDelegate as wel. Make your AppDelegate conform to the RCTBridgeModule protocol, and I think you should be able to access the file through native modules.

Comment: I'm not sure how native modules helps in this operation.  As I understand it, the flow for native modules is:

iOS App Launches > RN initializes > RN app loads native modules > RN app uses native module > iOS executes native code

For my flow I need:
user opens file in my app > iOS app initializes with URL > RN initializes with URL

After this discussion I might be able to use native modules if I instead had:
user opens file in my app > iOS app initializes with URL and saves it in memory > React App initializes > React app uses native module to access saved memory

Comment: Are you talking about deep linking?

https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe this is more inline with what you're trying to do?

Comment: @SamuelMarkoe Yes!  I think that will do it.  Will try to go down that path and post an update when I have a conclusion